# FindOne embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I have got `bars` embedded in `foos`, so now I want to get one particular `bar` from `foo`:

```
foo = db.foos.findOne()
bar = foo.bars.findOne({property: 'Hello World'})
```

So how can I reach this?

Comment: You did not read the very basic documentation on using embedded docs. Did you?

Comment: no, you did not. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation

Comment: so, you believe this will return embedded document and not parent one? I am sure it won't

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have something like this:

```
foo 
{
   _id: 1,
   bars :[
      {name: "1"},
      {name: "2"}
   ]
}
```

So, mongodb queries always return only root documents:

```
db.foos.find({"bars.name": 1})
```

Above query will return all foos that contains bar with name equal "1". Get bar that you need then you can at the client side.

Also if you need only one item from embedded array you can use [slice and include only root documen](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields)t to load minimum of data:

```
db.foos.find({"bars.name": 1}, {bars:{$slice: 1}, _id: 1})
```

Above query will return all foos that contains bar with name equal "1", but it also only one matched nested bar and return only id of parent document, so then at client side you will need load first item from nested bars array.

Comment: but slice will return ONLy first `bar`: not the one I need

Comment: @fl00r: not first, but first matched by query.